# What is wrong with my mango tree, it’s loosing colour

Tags: plant-health, nutrients

[image]
Hello,
My Mango tree which is five years old was transplanted last year into the  ground after growing in a large pot. After transplanting, it grew really quickly and bore fruit for the first time.It is now about 5.9 feet high.
But, since late April, I have noticed some leaves are changing color. As shown in my picture some of the dark mature leaves have light green patches that are appearing randomly on them. Some other leaves have these patches and browned dry edges. Some of the newer leaves aren’t greening fast enough and have dying edges already.
After researching these symptoms I decided to apply a Potassium Sulfate foliar spray onto the leaves and watered the plant with the same solution adequately.
I think it is important to mention that there was a clay bed on the garden. This clay bed was mostly removed before the Mango tree was planted there. Also, despite the worsening state of the older leaves, the tree is growing new leaves and branches as if it were completely healthy.
I just want to know exactly what my plant's complication is.
Thank you.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out please? I'm guessing it's a mobile nutrient deficiency?